# Find number of Cuboids in a larger Cuboid

Tags: geometry, volume

[image: A snapshot of the problem]

This is a question posed to my brother in Grade 5.

- What would be the **general approach** to solve-
  **How many cuboids of dimensions** $a*b*c$ are there in a cuboid of dimension $d*e*f$?

**My brothers approach:**

- Just get the ratio $\frac{d*e*f}{a*b*c}$ and round it off.

**My approach:**

- **Check 1**: Each of $d$, $e$, $f$ must be larger than $a$, $b$, $c$
- **Check 2**: Each of $d$, $e$, $f$ must be divisible by $a$ or $b$ or $c$. That is $\frac{a}{d}=0$, $\frac{b}{e}=0$, $\frac{c}{f}=0$.
  So my answer would be:
  $$\frac{24\times 30\times 28}{3\times 5\times 2}=672$$

Comment: if you picturise it you will get the answer as$$(d-a+1)*(e-b+1)*(f-c+1)$$

Comment: HINT: Combinations

Comment: By the way, the notation $d|a$ is read "$d$ divides $a$", i.e., $a$ is divisible by $d$, not the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your brother's approach is more nearly correct: since there is no requirement that all the rectangular blocks should be cut out in the same orientation, the only obvious upper bound is that the volume of the little blocks should not exceed the volume of the big block.  That upper bound is
$$
\frac{24\cdot 30 \cdot 29}{5\cdot 3 \cdot 2}=696.
$$

You still need to show that that upper bound can be achieved, though.  So consider first cutting the $24\times 30 \times 29$ block into a $24\times 30\times 25$ block plus a $24\times 30 \times 4$ block.  The first block can be cut into small blocks with no waste because $2|24$, $3|30$, and $5|25$.  The second can also be cut with no waste because $3|24$, $5|30$, and $2|4$.  So the correct answer is in fact $696$.

Comment: Thanks,So if the requirement was to get them in the same orientation the answer would be:(24*30*28)/(5*3*2)?

Comment: I think that's right, yes… $29$ divided by $2$ has a smaller remainder than $29$ divided by $3$ or $5$, and there's no waste along the other two dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

lengthwise number of $a$ units in $d$ is $(d-a+1)$
 breadthwise number of $b$ units in $e$ is $(e-b+1)$ 
 heightwise number of $c$ units in $f$ is $(f-c+1)$ 
combining ,number of cuboids that can be formed is$$(d-a+1)*(e-b+1)*(f-c+1)$$

Comment: Can you explain how on earth you get $(d-a+1)$?

Comment: Very clear answer with no explanation.

Comment: But it has to do with combinations @OldJohn

Comment: @DonLarynx I am sorry, but I still have absolutely no idea where $d-a+1$ comes from, and the final answer given in Suraj's answer disagrees completely with my calculations in some simple examples.

Comment: The problem is about cutting a block into many small blocks and counting the small blocks.  Not about excising a *single* small block and counting how many ways that can be done such that all remaining dimensions are integers (which is what this answers).

Comment: And even if it *were* a problem of combinatorics (which it isn't… this is a fifth-grade problem, it's about understanding volume…), this answer would be wrong, because it doesn't consider different orientations for the small block.

Comment: when we change the orientation the dimension also changes.just think.