# Number of small cuboids inside a larger cube

Tags: geometry

> How many small cuboids of dimension $2$ m × $3$ m × $4$ m can be
>   accommodated in a cube of side $22$ m?

(This is similar to the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560886/find-number-of-cuboids-in-a-larger-cuboid) from this site. But probably more complex)

This question is available in the following sources.
 [Source 1: quora.com](https://www.quora.com/How-many-small-cuboids-of-dimension-2m-X-3m-x-4-m-can-be-accommodated-in-a-cube-of-side-22-m)
[Source 2: careerbless.com](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=3456#top)
[Source 3: m4maths.com](http://www.m4maths.com/post-13100-How-many-small-cuboids-of-dimension-2m-X-3m-x-4-m-can-be-accommodated-in-a-cube-of-side.html)

As clear from  Quora.com and careerbless.com, answer cannot be $\dfrac{22^3}{2 \times 3 \times 4}=443$, but $443$ is an upper bound. This is clear because there is some waste of material.

Both these sources give answer as $385$ . This is also straight forward, because $22/2=11\ $, $\ 22/3 =7$ (avoiding fraction), $\ 22/4 =5$ (avoiding fraction) and total number of small cuboids possible is then $11 \times 7 \times 5= 385$

But in, careerbless.com, one more option is given by showing the different orientation of the small cuboids. See the table given in my link. Thus they show $442$ smalll cuboids can be fit inside the actual cube, if different orientation and rotation is taken into account.

> I want to know the right answer for this problem. Whether it is $385$
>   or $442$ ? If $442$ is also a possible answer, how this can be generalized (i.e., is there any generalized approach or formula), because that process appears too complex for me. Please help.

Comment: I can get to 440 without too much effort: it's easy to come up with a 10x12x2 cuboid, lay out four of those in a 22x22x22 thing with a 2x2x2 hole in the middle, and stack 11 piles of that; this gives a 2x2x22 hole through a 22x22x22 block.  This is obviously too small for things to fit in.

Comment: @Dan Uznanski, so 440 is maximum possible or still 442 is possible?

Comment: I haven't gotten to 442 yet.  if there's a way to get two 4x2 holes (or a single 4x4 or 2x8 hole) in a layer, it would actually be possible to get 443.

Comment: 442: four 6x16x2s arranged around a 10x10x2 hole; put a 6x8x2 and a 4x6x2 in the hole.  Stack this layer 11 times.  then fill the 4x4x2 hole with things on their "side" so they're 3 tall, and the 2x6x2 hole with things "standing up" so they're 4 tall.  This leaves a 2x6x2 hole and a 4x4x1 hole at the top.  Which actually... yes, I have 443.  Stand by for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for the 443 tiles of 2×3×4 cells each, in a 22×22×22 volume:

[image: 443 2x3x4 tiles in a 22x22x22 volume]

To "build" the solution:

1. Use 11 layers of tiles as shown above in the leftmost picture, to fill in the volume except for a centered 2×2×16 volume, and 2×2×22 on top of it.

   Since each layer takes 5 + 4×6 + 5 = 34 tiles, this step uses a total of 11 × 34 = 374 tiles.
2. Rotate the volume so that you face the void.
3. Fill in deeper 2×2×16 volume, as shown in the middle figure. This will leave a 4×1×2 hole. This uses 29 additional tiles.
4. Fill in the top two layers as shown in the rightmost figure. This will leave four 1×1×2 holes. This uses 40 additional tiles.

The total number of tiles used is 11×34+29+40 = 443.

The entire volume consists of 22×22×22 = 10,648 cells. Each tile occupies 2×3×4 = 24 cells. The 443 tiles occupy 443×24 = 10,632 cells. We left 1×4×2 + 1×1×2 + 1×1×2 + 1×1×2 + 1×1×2 = 16 cells unoccupied. (Each black box signifies two unoccupied cells, since each layer in the figures above is two cells thick.)

The sum of occupied and unoccupied cells, 10,632 + 16 = 10,648, matches the number of cells in the volume.

Note that there are many other equivalent solutions, as especially in step 3 you can choose where the 1×4×2 void ends up.

---

These types of [packing problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems) are generally considered *hard*, in the sense that there are no simple generic algorithms that yield optimal solutions. Often, optimal solutions are found through various types of searches, sometimes even brute-force solutions.

I stumbled onto this solution by accident.

Comment: Yours is nicer than mine.

Comment: @DanUznanski: You could make it even nicer, by rotating the bottom middle tile in the middle picture, so the 1×4×2 hole would be at bottom center, making it horizontally symmetric. I honestly don't know how it occurred to me to do the rotation, making the rest of the filling really easy.

Comment: @DanUznanski: Couldn't help it, had to replace the image with one with the 1×4×2 hole is at the bottom middle. Now its horizontally symmetric and pretty :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

These green blocks are lying flat; there's 38 of them.  Make ten layers of this.  Then, fill in the blue area with six layers of blocks lying on their side; now there is a 2x4x4 space above it.  Similarly, fill in the orange area with five layers of blocks standing up; now there is no space above those.  Now, partially fill the remaining 2x4x4 space with a single 2x3x4 block.

Finally, you need one more 22x22 layer that has four 1x1x2 spots open.  You can use the blue display from Nominal Animal's post, or you can use the one below that I came up with.

Final score: 10 layers of 38, plus five layers of 2, plus six layers of 2, plus 1, plus one layer of 40.  380 + 10 + 12 + 1 + 40 = 443.

[image]